# The longest binary number from list of 200 bits decimal numbers

Tags: c#

I have several strings that represent the numbers as decimal. These numbers have <= 200 bits in binary view. I need to find the longest in binary view number from the list.

For example, I have several strings:

"10", "20", "32", "64". The longest length from the list will be 7  (64 => 1000000)

the main problem is that the numbers has 200 bits in binary view.

Comment: Well the length in binary is going to be the log to base 2 of the number, or log to some arbitrary base divided by the log of 2 to the same base. What mechanism are you using to store your large integers - some BigInteger class? Does it have a log function? It looks like [the built-in one does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268364.aspx).

Comment: Do you need to find the longest number, or the *length* of the longest number? (You've said one thing in the first paragraph, but then given a different result in the answer.)

Comment: @Rup It might even be sufficient to just parse the string as a `double` (which easily supports large enough values) and calculate the log of that - no need for "big" classes. (Since you don't need your in-memory representation of the number to be exact.)

Comment: is there any negative numbers?

Comment: the longest number will be the highest as well, so i am assuming you do not actually want that, as it is trivial. The actual length is given by Rup :)

Comment: I need the length of the biggest number.

I forgot about the log function, It resolves my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the strings as [`BigInteger`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and calculate the number of bits in the number using the formula `floor(log_b(x)) + 1` (to find the number of digits of `x` in base `b`). Something along these lines:

```
var bigInts = myStrings.Select(x => BigInteger.Parse(x));
BigInteger biggestInt = bigInts.Max();
int bitsInBiggest = (int)Math.Floor(BigInteger.Log(biggestInt, 2)) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on the question, but as Rup suggests, are you asking 2^200?

[2^200 == 1.6069 x 10^60.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E200)
Which will give you a length of 61 decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the numbers as strings, as you only need to know if one number is larger than another. Use the decimal representation of a binary number, double that number progressively and filter out numbers that are smaller than that until you don't have any numbers left. Then you know how many bits where needed for the largest number.

Example:

```
string[] numbers = { "10", "20", "32", "64" };

string binary = "1";
int bits = 1;

do {

  numbers = numbers
    .Where(n => n.Length > binary.Length || n.CompareTo(binary) > 0)
    .ToArray();

  string s = "";
  int carry = 0;
  for (int i = binary.Length - 1; i >= 0 || carry > 0; i--) {
    if (i >= 0) {
      carry += (binary[i] - '0') * 2;
    }
    s = (char)((carry % 10) + 48) + s;
    carry /= 10;
  }
  binary = s;
  bits++;

} while (numbers.Length > 0);

Console.WriteLine(bits - 1);
```

Output:

```
7
```